# How much would it cost for a PC to fund a metropolis-wide party night?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, economy

How much would it cost for a PC to fund a metropolis-wide party night?

When I say metropolis-wide party night, picture your run-of-the-mill festive fantasy village where food and drinks are in abundance (and not necessarily cheap stuff), musicians and staff work for hours and whatnot. A single PC provides everything.

Now, how much could it cost to fund such an event for, say, ~20000 people (rounded up to account for extra expenses)? Even a rough estimate would be alright.

Comment: This question seems like it could very reasonably be answered in a way that draws primarily on source material. For those who want to close it, consider explaining why.

Comment: "Why" what? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Anyway while there are many costs that could be extrapolated from source material (like food and drinks, that could just be multiplied) some other costs (like, for example, the musicians) I'm not sure. Or maybe there are things I could have forgotten about or left out, in which case help would be appreciated. Of course people could ask for clarification/more details before voting to close, but I half-expected that for a question like this.

Comment: I’ll be clearer: anyone who wants to close this should explain why they think it should be closed.

Comment: Ah, got it. It was phrased weird

Comment: @Snakehelm Musician costs wouldn't be hard to estimate - the money that can be earned using the perform skills is listed in the core rules. I believe this question is answerable in its current state - but I also believe it could be improved by including more information about the party you want to hold: Exactly what do you want it to include? Just booze, food, and music? Or do you want to include, I dunno, a rousing 20,000 person game of pass-the-parcel?

Comment: Mainly those you listed (drinks, food and music). Suggestions are welcome tho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Slightly more than 200 000 gp for a group of 20 000**

For reference: this is about the same price as a +10 equivalent weapon. I would not consider this a wise investment.

*The Food:*

A banquet is listed as a price for 10 gp per person served, and is described as such[(1)](https://aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Banquet%20(per%20person)):

> A banquet includes several food courses, good drinks, and servants to bring the food and take away empty plates. The listed price is for having a banquet at a restaurant (though some restaurant owners can be hired to serve a banquet at a private location). The price listed above is per person.

There is no adjustment stated to the price for having an banquet outside of a restaurant (which presumably does not fit 20 000 people). This comes out to 200 000 gp plus possibly an unspecified amount for catering somewhere else.

*The Entertainment:*

A "memorable" performance (DC 25) is listed as being able to earn 1d6 (average 3.5) gp per day[(2)](https://aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Perform), and has a perform DC at the high end of what low-level NPCs can hope to achieve. How much you spend total would depend on how many people can be occupied with one entertainer, but what I would consider to be a conservative estimate of 10:1 guests:performers gives only a 3% increase in cost over the banquet itself, assuming average wages.

Comment: I guess this would be on the high end of the spectrum, cost-wise. But I'm wondering, would multiple Good Meals (Good meals might consist of bread and pastries, beef, peas, and ale or wine) possibly obtain the same effect (Maybe even having 5 per person)? Of course that would exclude the staff, but even having 500 people working and paying them 5 GP for that evening only would cost slightly more than 50000, a quarter of the banquet option.

Comment: @snakehelm optimization is going to depend very strongly on exactly what you’re trying to achieve. This is likely as good as you’re going to get for a strictly textual answer.